# "Support team lead" or "support team leader"

Tags: word-choice, business-language

Which is correct: *support team lead* or *support team leader*?

I think *team leader* should be correct since *leader* is a persona while *lead* looks more like a verb. But I see some multinational companies use *team lead* in their job description. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Check the dictionary for "lead":http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lead
a. The first or foremost position.
b. **One occupying such a position; a leader.**

Comment: True, but what is the difference, JeffSahol?

Comment: I meant that they are synonymous...posted as an answer, @Thursagen.

Answer (score 12):

In my experience, a team lead is appointed (by a manager), and is assumed to be taking on some leadership responsibilities in addition to his normal duties as a team member...generally for no extra pay, I might add.

In another sense, a *leader* is someone who "steps up" and takes on challenges and/or inspires others, regardless of whether they have the official standing to do so. I have never heard the word *lead* used in this sense.

Otherwise, though, the phrases "team lead" and "team leader" are synonymous.

Answer (score 2):

The only use of ‘lead’ to describe a person that the OED records is the theatrical one: one who plays the principal part in a play. I have not seen it used as a synonym for ‘leader’. ‘Support the team lead’ surely means something subtly different from ‘support the team leader’. It highlights the position and its role rather than the person occupying it.

Comment: I don't think, it was meant as "support the team lead(er)", but rather "lead(er) of the support team".

Answer (score 0):

Lead is for a leader who leads the work without authority but by influence and  he/she does not have direct reports. 
Leader is for a leader who leads the work by having direct reports led by influence and authority together. So the difference is around having/not having direct reports

Comment: Generally speaking, anyone who has direct reports will be called a Support Team Manager.  Nobody in an organisation should lead without authority.

Comment: citations for your answer are always helpful